# how to avoid garbage option error on grep command

Tags: bash, shell-script, ps

i need to check whether a process is running or not on server. But challenge is , the keyword I am using is not the userid , it's part of the o/p or ps command.

When i am running as `ps -ef | grep -v $$ | grep xenon` , I am getting as

> error: garbage option
>
> Usage:  ps [options]
>
> Try 'ps --help '   or 'ps --help
>   '  for additional help text.
>
> For more details see ps(1). xenon is not running, please check
>   error: garbage option

On server , some reason I see no o/p for `pgrep` , which will resolve my challenge. He is the o/p from server.

```
$ps -ef | grep xenon
venom   3157  95310  0 23:08 pts/5    00:00:00 grep --color=auto xenon
root      45943      1  0 Apr12 ?        00:17:47 /opt/xenon/sganet/agent/lib64/sganetwatchdog -vm=/opt/xenon/sganet/agent/lib64/sganetos -logdir /opt/xenon/sganet/log -ini ../conf/ruxitwatchdog.ini
root      45981  45943  2 Apr12 ?        08:20:31 /opt/xenon/sganet/agent/lib64/sganetos -Dcom.compuware.apm.WatchDogTimeout=9000 -Dcom.compuware.apm.WatchDogPort=5000
$pgrep xenon
$pgrep -c xenon
0
$
```

Here is the script I wrote basically to check for validating multiple process running on the server.

```
#!/bin/bash
set +x
USER=`whoami`
#pg='ps -ef | grep -v $USER | '
pg='ps ax | grep -v grep | '
#--------function to check process ---------#
check_process() {

  $pg $1 >/dev/null && echo -e "$1 is running" || echo -e "$1 is not running, please check "
}

#--------Checking process on the server---------#

echo -e "\n\n checking the processes"
check_process xenon
check_process upnew
```

Comment: Did you try `pgrep -f xenon`?  Also related: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shell parameter expansion happens *after* the high-level parsing of pipes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01) breaks the line into structured commands, so your function body runs as though you'd written

```
ps ax '|' grep -v grep '|'
```

- that is, with the pipes as literal arguments to `ps`. That's why you're getting the error *from `ps`* (not from `grep`!) complaining it doesn't understand the `|` argument.

You could fix that a couple of ways:

1. Just write the command into the function instead of using the `pg` variable. This seems like the best version to me, but your actual script may be more complicated.
2. If there's a real need for something like that, use a function to contain the pipeline instead:

   ```
   pg_cmd_1() {
       ps ax | grep -v grep | $1
   }
   pg=pg_cmd_1
   ```

   and carry on as-is. That would let you define additional functions and change the `pg` variable dynamically to use them if necessary.

---

In addition, as currently written your script was trying to run `ps ax | grep -v grep | xenon`, which I think still isn't what you want (missing a `grep`?).

Comment: Yes @Michael , `grep` is missing . I have copied a wrong line from console.

Comment: I have tried as you suggested , I am getting diff error now as `pg_cmd: command not found
xenon is not running, please check`

did i miss something ?

`pg_cmd_1() {
    ps ax | grep -v $$ | $1
}
pg=pg_cmd
check_process() {

  $pg >/dev/null && echo -e "$1 is running" || echo -e "$1 is not running, please check "
}`

Comment: It should have been `pg=pg_cmd_1`, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Hello Michael ,

I thought , it was working , but looks there is something not looking correctly because of my ps command. 

though the process is not running , its is showing as running . 
This is the condition I am checking `$pg  >/dev/null && echo -e "$1 is running" || echo -e "$1 is not running, please check "`

`pg` is your logic.

Comment: I have marked as working answer is because , as I need to publish this script and option 1 will work to me . Just that I need to add at many places.

Comment: You left the argument out.

Comment: Sorry , I didn`t catch that . I see no error on way I have followed . Can you highlight for me?